# Gnuplot: automatic placing of x2 tic labels

Tags: gnuplot

I've got data that I want to plot in gnuplot that looks something like this:

```
1.08 1 4.8
1.53 2 5.9
2.11 3 5.1
2.60 4 6.0
```

Not that it's terribly important, the first column is the running time of a genetic algorithm, the second column is the generation number, and the third is average fitness.

If I plot it using `plot datafile.dat using 1:3 with lines` it looks fine, with tics appropriately spaced. However, while I want the x-tics to be labelled with the time, I want the x2-tics to be labelled with the generation number. This is easy to do with `plot datafile.dat using 1:3:x2ticlabels(2) with lines`, but for the x2-axis it adds a tick for every single line in the data file, instead of automatically choosing an appropriate number of tics.

My full data file has thousands of entries, which results in a solid black line at the top of the graph where the tics would be spaced, and a larger solid black line above where the labels would be placed. Even if I try to manually tell gnuplot how often to place tics on the graph using `set x2tics 100` it still displays them for every entry. Is there a way to fix this? Obviously I'd prefer which tics are shown to be automatically chosen, but if I have to do it manually that's fine. The full gnuplot config file is pretty basic, just:

```
set logscale y 10
set x2tics
plot datafile.dat using 1:3:x2ticlabels(2) with lines
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will only put a label for every other line in the datafile.

```
plot 'test.dat' u 1:3:x2ticlabels(int($0)%2==0?stringcolumn(2):'')
```

One thing that is a little interesting is that the tics don't quite line up with the points.  I haven't figured out why yet.  With thousands of points, you're probably not likely to notice, but with your example datafile with 4 points, it's noticeable.

Unfortunately, it still draws a tic on the axis for every line in the datafile.  `set x2tics scale 0` will make those tics go away completely.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. Regarding the alignment issue, in my file the first entry is at t=2.5, and the last at t=22.5, and gnuplot scaled the x-axis from 0-25. I noticed the generation numbers seemed to be placed across the entire plot, (so "0" was placed above t=0 instead of 2.5), which might provide some clue as to why they don't line up correctly. Manually setting the xrange makes it less noticeable, but I'm not sure the cause either.

Comment: @user1535823 -- I think the alignment problem would go away if you explicitly set both ranges to be the same thing:  `set xrange [1:10]; set x2range [1:10]`, but I'm not positive, and I don't understand why they don't both autoscale to the same range.